# Laravel - How to store data from dynamic form field?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to store data from the dynamic form field.

And this is my code :

My Controller :

```
 /*
 * This is For Create Question
 *
 */
public function CreateQuestion(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'exercise' => 'required',
        'question' => 'required',
        'opt1' => 'required',
        'opt2' => 'required',
        'opt3' => 'required',
        'opt4' => 'required',
    ]);

    $inputs = $request->all();

    foreach ($inputs as $input)
        {
            Question::create(array(
                'exercise'=>$input['exercise'],
                'question'=>$input['question'],
                'opt1'=>$input['opt1'],
                'opt2'=>$input['opt2'],
                'opt3'=>$input['opt3'],
                'opt4'=>$input['opt4'],
            ));
        }

    return back()->with('success','Soal Berhasil dikirim.');
}
```

and I use names like exercise[] for the form.

And the result of my code is :

```
 ErrorException
 Illegal string offset 'exercise'
```

Comment: why are you using foreach? are you expecting array from your request?

Comment: yes, I have a form, where that form can add more fields. so I have one form for several rows in one table.

Comment: Can you add code of your form?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping over `$inputs`, then you're essentially trying to create a `Question` record for every form input... Don't do that. Get rid of the `foreach()` and access the inputs properly:

```
Question::create(array(
    'exercise' => $request->input('exercise'),
    'question' => $request->input('question'),
    'opt1' => $request->input('opt1'),
    'opt2' => $request->input('opt2'),
    'opt3' => $request->input('opt3'),
    'opt4' => $request->input('opt4')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code, here I can get all the values. But it appears like this:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of 
the type array, string given,
```

My New Controller :

```
 /*
 * This is For Create Question
 *
 */
public function createQuestion(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'exercise' => 'required',
        'question' => 'required',
        'opt1' => 'required',
        'opt2' => 'required',
        'opt3' => 'required',
        'opt4' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Init
    $inputs = $request->all();


    Question::create(array(
        'exercise' => $inputs['exercise'],
        'question' => $inputs['question'],
        'opt1' => $inputs['opt1'],
        'opt2' => $inputs['opt2'],
        'opt3' => $inputs['opt3'],
        'opt4' => $inputs['opt4'],
    ));

    return back()->with('success','Soal Berhasil dikirim.');
}
```

My New form :

```
 <form>
   <select name="exercise[]"></select>
   <textarea name="question[]"></textarea>
   <input name="opt1[]"></input>
   <input name="opt2[]"></input>
   <input name="opt3[]"></input>
   <input name="opt4[]"></input>
   <!-- This is the add more filed button -->
   <button name="addMoreSoal" id="addMoreSoal"addMoreSoal">Add More 
   Soal</button> 
   <button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

And thanks to all who have tried to help me, but I need more help for this one...

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Lewis said, "you are trying to create a Question record for every form input",
another way, you can pass all the inputs inside the `create` method to insert a new question record to the database

```php
public function CreateQuestion(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'exercise' => 'required',
        'question' => 'required',
        'opt1' => 'required',
        'opt2' => 'required',
        'opt3' => 'required',
        'opt4' => 'required',
    ]);

    $inputs = $request->all();

    Question::create($inputs);

    return back()->with('success','Soal Berhasil dikirim.');
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but only the last additional fields were sent.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function CreateQuestion(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'exercise' => 'required',
        'question' => 'required',
        'opt1' => 'required',
        'opt2' => 'required',
        'opt3' => 'required',
        'opt4' => 'required',
    ]);

    $inputs = $request->all();

    foreach ($inputs['exercise'] as $key => $exercise)
        {
            Question::create(array(
                'exercise'=>$exercise,
                'question'=>$inputs['question'][key],
                'opt1'=>$inputs['opt1'][key],
                'opt2'=>$inputs['opt2'][key],
                'opt3'=>$inputs['opt3'][key],
                'opt4'=>$inputs['opt4'][key],
            ));
        }

    return back()->with('success','Soal Berhasil dikirim.');
}
```

Comment: Result : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() *_*,  you missed "s" by the way.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my answer.

Comment: Sorry, Thank you,  for your answer. But its doesn't work for me.... 

Comment: This is the result : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()